# How to count each word from comma separated column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example table: users

User table

```
| id | languages                     |
| -- | --------------                |
| 1  |  Arabic, English, Spanish     |
| 2  | English, Other                |
| 3  | English, Arabic               |
```

Expect output

```
| language | total |
| -------- | ----- |
| Arabic   | 2     |
| English  | 3     |
| Spanish  | 1     |
| Other    | 1     |
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string.

Comment: Parse your CVS values to separate values then aggregate.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question with the strings, but here's a fiddle if you change you're data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=786b5021507d90c638aaf7bcf58d9cae